# How can I control five hundred 250 mA electromagnets with shift registers and MOSFETs at the same time?

Tags: power-supply, shift-register, electromagnet

At the moment I control 16 electromagnets.
I will later daisy chain the shift register control boards to control 500 electromagnets 250 mA each at 24 V (could be 12 V) with shift registers and MOSFETs at the same time but the current consumption is huge 125 A. My 16 channel board can handle 8 A.

What power supply could I use?

Comment: Re-think/present the application: there may be approaches requiring power for state changes, only. The solenoids/electromagnets may need 250 mA when actuated, but 99 mA or 144 mA may do for steady state.

Comment: I notice the title asks *How to control* while in the body I read *How to power*.

Comment: my electromagnets are used  to catch needles , to hold it during a linear 50µs movement

Comment: Make breakout boards for a suitable amount with its own power supply? Are all on at the same time? What’s the duty cycle?

Comment: i don't use pwm it's a bitmap when it's activated it's becoming high like this: 0b0000011001100000

Comment: Is it acceptable for the entire lot to fail if the power supply fails, or would it be OK if there were several power supplies were used and maybe one failed? I am not familiar with the intricacies of catching needles.

Answer (score 2):

You see yourself faced with a task big enough to look a problem.
The general technique to tackle such is to break it into smaller parts, identical parts welcome:

Create modules of manageable complexity and power/current requirements.
3 kW DC is in the upper part of what a single 230/240 V outlet will handle easily.

It isn't by chance conductors carrying high currents are sometimes designated *rail*s:
In proximity, they exert force on each other to be reckoned with.

Not knowing other constraints such as cost, space, and options for getting rid of the heat, I might go for multiple 24 V supplies in the 1kW range.
This still means currents of about 40 A.

Answer (score 0):

You have not presented a schematic so that we know more details which could help us give you a better answer. 
As the user "greybeard" has noted in his comment, the activation current and the on-state current are different and could help reduce your power requirements.

If your circuit allows it, you could use the latching relays which only require power when changing their state, and zero power while remaining in their current state. They cost more, but they would GREATLY reduce your control power requirements. 
If only a few of your relays need to be actuated at a time, or if it's acceptable to actuate only one at a time, that would cut your supply requirements to almost nothing.

There could be more solutions to your problem, but you haven't given us more to go on.

Comment: *relays* does not match *electromagnets to catch needles to hold it during a linear 50µs movement*.

Comment: @greybeard I didn't catch that detail in the comments. Maybe if he provided a picture of what he needs done, it would help us give better answers.

Comment: `50µs movement` sounds ambitious anyway - that's ~20 kHz.

Comment: thank you ! as it is custom elctromagnets i will reduce the intensity to 22mA at around 1100 ohm

Comment: @Mastalyn I don't know if at that current you will be able to get the speed you need.

Comment: It's 500us sorry , my mistake when i wrote ! So it's gonna be ok

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what others have said, you can daisy chain the control signals (clock, data, and latch), but use multiple power supplies to distribute the current load. As long as everything shares a common ground reference, should work as intended.